# Can't access dynamic namespace using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm attempting to build an app that would use dynamic socket.io namespaces. I would prefer to use dynamic namespaces as opposed to rooms so that I can still use rooms within each namespace. Please let me know if the below isn't possible or if I am misunderstanding something about socket.io.

Say theoretically it's an app for dogs and cats to log in to and use. I don't want the events, messages, etc. from the dogs to be seen by the cats, and vice-versa. I would like the namespaces to be dynamic in the event that maybe another type of pet, like a raccoon, would like to start using the app, and can just jump on and be sent to its appropriate namespace.

**server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = require('express')(); //express app
const httpServer = require('http').Server(app); //http server
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer); //Socket.IO.Server

//namespaces
let namespaces = {
    'pet': new RegExp('^\\/pet\\/(\\\w+)$'); //RegExp evaluates to '/pet/:petType'
}

//The below structure for setting up a dynamic namespace was found on the
//socket.io server API docs
io.of(namespaces.pet).on('connect', (socket) => {
    const petNamespace = socket.nsp; //sets petNamespace as type SocketIO.Namespace
                                     //e.g. petNamespace.name === '/pet/dog'
                                     //this is the namespace i am having trouble accessing 

    console.log("socket.io: Connected to", petNamespace.name);

    //for testing purposes
    petNamespace.on('test', (namespaceUser) => console.log(`${petNamespace.name} received a test event from ${namespaceUser}.`)
}

app.use(cors(), bodyParser.json());

//Start server
httpServer.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server started on port 4000.'));
```

**client.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

//Create a new namespace for dogs
//The below does NOT return the petNamespace, rather just a regular socket as
//io.connect('http://localhost:4000') would.
const dog1 = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/pet/dog', { forceNew: true });
const dog2 = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/pet/dog', { forceNew: true }); 

//Create a new namespace for cats
const cat1 = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/pet/cat', { forceNew: true });

dog1.emit('test', 'dog1'); //Intent: emit test event ONLY to the dog namespace
```

**Expected Output**

> socket.io: Connected to /pet/dog
>
> socket.io: Connected to /pet/cat
>
> **/pet/dog received a test event from dog1**

**Actual Output**

> socket.io: Connected to /pet/dog
>
> socket.io: Connected to /pet/cat

The issue is the following line:
`const petNamespace = socket.nsp` in **server.js**. I can emit events from the server from this namespace, but I cannot access it from the client. I followed the structure of the API docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api#server-of-nsp).

How can I access petNamespace from **client.js**?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
io.of(namespaces.pet).on('connection', ...
```

And...

```
socket.on('test', (namespaceUser) => console.log(`${petNamespace.name} received a test event from ${namespaceUser}.`)
```

Not tested yet, but it should work.